# Форма обратной связи, что подкрутить

Tags: php, html

Есть страница, на ней форма обратной связи. Есть файл php. Все лежит в корне сайта. Форма не присылает письмо, помогите.

код формы

```
<!-- CONTACT FORM starts here, Go to contact.php and add your email ID,thats 
it.-->    
                <form role="form" action="contact.php">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" 
id="name" placeholder="Name">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" 
id="email" placeholder="Email">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
                        </div>


                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="25" cols="10" placeholder="  Message Texts..."></textarea>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default submit-btn form_submit">SEND MESSAGE</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- END FORM --> 
            </div>
```

Вот код php:

```
<?php 

//======================================================================
// Variables
//======================================================================


//E-mail address. Enter your email
define("__TO__", "vitmax55@mail.ru");

//Success message
define('__SUCCESS_MESSAGE__', "Your message has been sent. We will reply 
soon. Thank you!");

//Error message 
define('__ERROR_MESSAGE__', "Your message hasn't been sent. Please try 
again.");

//Messege when one or more fields are empty
define('__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FIELDS__', "Please fill out  all fields");


//======================================================================
// Do not change
//======================================================================

//E-mail validation
function check_email($email){
if(!@eregi("^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z] 
{2,3})$", $email)){
    return false;
} else {
    return true;
}
}

 //Send mail
 function send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers){
 if(@mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers)){
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'success', 'msg' => 
 __SUCCESS_MESSAGE__));
  } else {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => __ERROR_MESSAGE__));
  }
  }

//Get data form and send mail
if(isset($_POST['name']) and isset($_POST['mail']) and 
isset($_POST['messageForm'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$subjectForm = $_POST['subjectForm'];
$messageForm = $_POST['messageForm'];

if($name == '') {
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your 
name."));
    exit();
} else if($mail == '' or check_email($mail) == false){
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter valid 
e-mail."));
    exit();
} else if($messageForm == ''){
    echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => "Please enter your 
message."));
    exit();
} else {
    $to = __TO__;
    $subject = $subjectForm . ' ' . $name;
    $message = '
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Mail from '. $name .'</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table style="width: 500px; font-family: arial; font-size: 14px;" 
border="1">
        <tr style="height: 32px;">
          <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Name: 
</th>
          <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. 
 $name .'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 32px;">
          <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">E-mail: 
 </th>
          <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. 
  $mail .'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 32px;">
          <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Subject: 
 </th>
          <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. 
  $subjectForm .'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="height: 32px;">
          <th align="right" style="width:150px; padding-right:5px;">Message: 
  </th>
          <td align="left" style="padding-left:5px; line-height: 20px;">'. 
  $messageForm  .'</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $mail . "\r\n";

    send_mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
}
} else {
echo json_encode(array('info' => 'error', 'msg' => 
__MESSAGE_EMPTY_FIELDS__));
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками, например [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Там всё просто: создаёте объект $mail = new PHPMailer(true); 
Передаёте параметры и отправляете письмо.